# php database connection fail redirect

Tags: php, sql, database, database-connection

I want to set up a database connetion, if the connection fails the user should be redirected to an error page, could you help?
Here is my current connection code:

```
<?php
    $hostname='localhost'; 
    $user='username';
    $pass='pasddword'; 
    $dbase='db_name';
    $connection = mysql_connect("$hostname" , "$user" , "$pass") 
            or die ("Can't connect to MySQL");
    $db = mysql_select_db($dbase , $connection) or die ("Can't select database.");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    // DO REDIRECT
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    // DO REDIRECT
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using header (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Below example taken from https://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    //die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: If you die, you can't redirect after.